# Google Sheets Query Where Cell value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm looking for help editing a Google Sheets formula. I want the formula to Import Range from another worksheet where value equals a specified cell. I can only make the where in the formula equal a hard-coded text. Can someone help?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BoIre_wWE6yfiFvLseWGn3XNqK4gUS2wqdVenR32q2M/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZtd4188cA2zG1ZeR_CisJbH6ykxjzNvmmr3LSeEXHk/edit?usp=sharing

Formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BoIre_wWE6yfiFvLseWGn3XNqK4gUS2wqdVenR32q2M/edit#gid=20780806", "CM!A2:G3000"),"SELECT Col1,Col5 WHERE (Col3 = 'Cross Fit')")
```

I want it to reference cell C1 instead of "Cross Fit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- do it like this:

  ```
  =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1BoIre_wWE6yfiFvLseWGn3XNqK4gUS2wqdVenR32q2M", "CM!A2:G"),
   "select Col1,Col5 where Col3 = '"&C1&"'")
  ```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly!